# Can't authorize github from git

Tags: git, github

I created a commit for my repo, but I can't push it.

```
23:19:43 emre@fedora:~/Projects/dynamic-wallpaper% git config --global user.name "ramazanemreosmanoglu"
23:22:18 emre@fedora:~/Projects/dynamic-wallpaper% git config --global user.email "ramazanemreosmanoglu@gmail.com"
23:22:22 emre@fedora:~/Projects/dynamic-wallpaper% git push                                                       
Username for 'https://github.com': ramazanemreosmanoglu
Password for 'https://ramazanemreosmanoglu@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: 'https://github.com/ramazanemreosmanoglu/dynamic-wallpaper/' için kimlik doğrulaması başarısız (This means authorizing unsuccess)
```

Comment: Do you have the newest version of git? Does it work with a PAT (personal access token)?

Comment: Yes PAT is worked for me. Thank you :)

Comment: [`user.name` is not a username, but a personal name](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatshouldIputincodeusernamecode).  It has no effect on authentication whatever.

Comment: My guess is that when you respond to “Password for 'https://ramazanemreosmanoglu@github.com'” you are getting the password wrong. In any case SSH is better...

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Github settings, select developer settings.
2. Choose Personal Access Tokens (PAT)
3. Click to generate new token, and check repo permissions.
4. Copy your token.

After running `git push` command, type your username to username input, and paste your token to password input. (You should to press Ctrl+Shift+V for paste text to terminal)